# Change googlemaps marker when clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am attempting to create a javascript function that will change the color of a Google Maps marker when it is clicked. Then, if a new marker is clicked, it will revert the old marker to its original color and change the new marker.

This is where my `changeMarker(marker, i)` function is called

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            changeMarker(marker, i);
        }
    })(marker, i));
```

And this is my `changeMarker()` function

```
function changeMarker(marker, i) {
    if(lastMarker) {
        lastMarker.setMap(null);
        console.log("Last Marker Removed");
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(buisnesses[lastID][1], buisnesses[lastID][2]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: buisnesses[lastID][0],
            icon: ("http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/0099FF/")
        });
        console.log("Last Marker Replaced");
    }

    marker.setMap(null);
    console.log("New Marker Removed");
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(buisnesses[i][1], buisnesses[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: buisnesses[i][0],
        icon: ("http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/D75C37/")
    });
    console.log("New Marker Created");
    lastMarker = newMarker;
    lastID = i;
}
```

Because I could not find out any way to simply alter the `icon` field of an already created marker, I resorted to removing the marker and replacing it each time a color change needed to happen. However, this implementation is giving me very inconsistent results (never replaces the first marker when a new marker is pressed for the first time, certain markers do nothing when pressed, etc...).

Any ideas if there are simpler ways to do this? I will be the first to admit I am not the best at javascript, so hopefully someone can point out an error I made along the way.

Thanks!

Comment: If you post a good question, you should not deleted it. SO keeps good questions, so that other can search and find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is:

```
marker.setIcon({});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: Well how did I miss that... thanks a bunch